# Why stdin.readline doesn't read until the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, stdin

I'm new to python and i try to send information to one subprocess from other python script but the subprocess dont read anything until the main stop sending.

I try to send new lines and lines that ends on '\n'. 
I understand that my child process is being blocked until the stream finishes, but if I send \ n or directly stdin.write ('\ n'), it should read correctly, but it does not

**Main process:**

```
import subprocess
import time

child = subprocess.Popen("python3 example.py", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
s = "this is the message"
print("MAIN:The child pid is: " + str(child.pid))
for i in range(0, 5):
    print("MAIN:iteration send:" + str(i))
    msg = s + "-" + str(i) + "\n"
    child.stdin.writelines(msg)
    time.sleep(1)
child.kill()
```

**Subprocess:**

```
import time
from sys import stdin

while True:
    try:
        print("CHILD:before read")
        s = stdin.readline()
        print("CHILD:after read")
        print("CHILD:message received is:" + s)
    except EOFError as err:
        print("M_READ_ERROR")
    time.sleep(1)
```

And my output is this

```
MAIN:The child pid is: 18041
MAIN:iteration send:0
CHILD:before read
MAIN:iteration send:1
MAIN:iteration send:2
MAIN:iteration send:3
MAIN:iteration send:4
CHILD:after read
CHILD:message received id:this is the message-0
```

But I expected something like:

```
MAIN:The child pid is: 18041
MAIN:iteration send:0
CHILD:before read
CHILD:after read
CHILD:message received id:this is the message-0
MAIN:iteration send:1
CHILD:before read
CHILD:after read
CHILD:message received id:this is the message-1
MAIN:iteration send:2
CHILD:before read
CHILD:after read
CHILD:message received id:this is the message-2
MAIN:iteration send:3
CHILD:before read
CHILD:after read
CHILD:message received id:this is the message-3
MAIN:iteration send:4
CHILD:before read
CHILD:after read
CHILD:message received id:this is the message-4
```

Comment: I don't see `stdin.readline()` in your code. You have only `stdin.read()` which works different then `readline()`

Comment: @furas i try both but the version i upload is the last I try. edited

Comment: use `child.stdin.flush()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipe is using the default buffer size for your system (`io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`). The reader is blocked because the buffer has not yet filled, so there's no indicator on the stream that a read is available.

To fix this, you need to control buffering. There are two ways.

First, you could do an explicit flush after each write.

```
child.stdin.writelines(msg)
child.stdin.flush()
```

This effectively implements line buffering, but in your own code.

Second, you could select buffering mode in the [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)() call by passing the `bufsize` kwarg. Positive bufsizes greater than 1 set a buffer size of that value, which means that your reader will get ready signals at intervals as that buffer is filled. But there are special cases too:

- 0 means *unbuffered*, so that each write flushes immediately;
- 1 means *line-buffered*, which is a special case where in user-space the io library scans writes for newlines and flushes after them.

You can pass `bufsize=1` to force flush after newlines. In python3, this depends on `universal_newlines=True`, but you have this already.

Comment: This works perfectly and your explanation is very clear.  thank you